# Ivy does not publish signature (.asc) files

Tags: ant, repository, publish, ivy, sonatype

I've a directory ready to be published with these files:

```
myapp-1.0-bin.jar
myapp-1.0-bin.jar.asc
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar.asc
myapp-1.0-pom.pom
myapp-1.0-pom.pom.asc
myapp-1.0-sources.jar
myapp-1.0-sources.jar.asc
```

The corresponding ivy.xml `publications` section is:

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="myapp" type="pom" ext="pom" conf="default" />
    <artifact name="myapp" type="bin" ext="jar" conf="default" />
    <artifact name="myapp" type="sources" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources" />
    <artifact name="myapp" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc" />
    <!-- The following lines have to be removed to publish correctly WITHOUT .asc files -->
    <artifact name="myapp" type="pom.asc" ext="pom.asc" conf="default"/>
    <artifact name="myapp" type="bin.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="default"/>
    <artifact name="myapp" type="sources.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="default" m:classifier="sources" />
    <artifact name="myapp" type="javadoc.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="default" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
</publications>
```

The ant publish task is:

```
<target name="ivyPublish-local-m2">
        <ivy:resolve />
        <ivy:publish resolver="local-m2-publish" pubrevision="${ivy.revision}" overwrite="true" publishivy="false">
            <artifacts pattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]" />
        </ivy:publish>
    </target>
```

This task should publish to a local directory, just for test.
The problem is the following error message:

```
impossible to publish artifacts for com.myorg#myapp;1.0: java.io.IOException: missing artifact com.myorg#myapp;1.0!myapp.pom.asc
```

If i remove the lines after the comment in ivy.xml the publish goes ahead but the content of the destination folder is:

```
myapp-1.0.pom
myapp-1.0.pom.md5
myapp-1.0.pom.sha1
myapp-1.0.jar
myapp-1.0.jar.md5
myapp-1.0.jar.sha1
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar.md5
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar.sha1
myapp-1.0-sources.jar
myapp-1.0-sources.jar.md5
myapp-1.0-sources.jar.sha1
```

Seems that the -bin and -pom types are dropped from the names (not so bad), but none of the corresponding .asc files are published.
I also tried to change the artifact pattern to:

```
<artifacts pattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext](.asc)" />
```

but with no success.
The questions are:

- How can I publish the .asc files?
- Can I publish the files without changing the names as happens with -pom and -bin?

Comment: It looks like you've got some overlap in your `type` and `ext` values. For example your pom asc entry has "pom.asc" set to both. This means the pattern `[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]` would resolve to "myapp-1.0-pom.asc.pom.asc". Also, I would suggest not putting "pom" and "bin" in the file names to indicate types, as that goes against Maven standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I standardized my artifacts as suggested by CAustin (no "-bin" and "-pom"). Now they are:

```
myapp-1.0.jar
myapp-1.0.jar.asc
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar
myapp-1.0-javadoc.jar.asc
myapp-1.0.pom
myapp-1.0.pom.asc
myapp-1.0-sources.jar
myapp-1.0-sources.jar.asc
```

With the following ivy.xml publications section:

```
<publications>
        <artifact type="pom" ext="pom" conf="default" /> 
        <artifact type="jar" ext="jar" conf="default" />
        <artifact type="sources" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources" />
        <artifact type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc" />

        <artifact type="pom.asc" ext="pom.asc" conf="default" />
        <artifact type="jar.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="default" />
        <artifact type="jar.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources" />
        <artifact type="jar.asc" ext="jar.asc" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc" />
    </publications>
```

and with build.xml call:

```
<ivy:publish resolver="local-m2-publish" pubrevision="${ivy.revision}" overwrite="true" publishivy="false">
            <artifacts pattern="${dist.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
        </ivy:publish>
```

Everything works!